# Using Python and Selenium why am I unable to find link by link text?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a list webelement that has a bunch of links within it.  The html looks like:

```
<li>
<a href="/shopping/cart_items/12444" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow" class="ss-delete"><span class="ss-icon"></span> Remove</a>
<a href="/sessions/new"><span class="ss-icon"></span> Sign in to save items</a
...
```

When I try to do something like:

```
link = element.find_element_by_link_text('Sign in to save items')
```

I get an error that says:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"link text","selector":"Sign in to save items"}

I have been able to find this link by instead doing a find_elements_by_tag_name('a') and then just using the link with the correct HREF, but I would like to understand why the first method fails.

Comment: try `element.find_element_by_link_text('Sign.in.to.save.items')`

Comment: If you have just loaded a new page, make sure to use WebDriverWait to make sure certain WebElements have already loaded. This seems to be a common issue when trying to identify by link text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me before that the `find_element_by_link_text` method sometimes works and sometimes doesn't work; even in a single case. I think it's not a reliable way to access elements; the best way is to use `find_element_by_id`.

But in your case, as I visit the page, there is no id to help you. Still you can try `find_elements_by_xpath` in 2 ways:

`1- Accessing title: find_element_by_xpath["//a[contains(@title = 'Sign in to save items')]"]`

`2- Accessing text: find_element_by_xpath["//a[contains(text(), 'Sign in to save items')]"]`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson on xpath.  That works better than the way I thought I would have to do it.

Comment: Pretty useful. I was trying the whole day with partial text and link text and never worked. Pretty good answer.

Comment: but it just worked the first time, the second time the same error message appears. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, most likely, in the extra spaces before or/and after the link text. You can still approach it with a "partial link text' match:

```
element.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Sign in to save items')
```